# Constructing entire function from two functions with the same simple pole

Tags: complex-analysis

Given two complex functions $f,g : \mathbb{C}\backslash\{z_0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ which are analytic everywhere in $\mathbb{C}$ except in one simple pole, which they have in the same point $z_0$. Does there exist a function $h : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that the function

$\Theta: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} : z \mapsto f(z) - h(z)g(z)$

does not have any singularities?

I fail to find a solid mathematical argument, and I doubt it is even possible to find such an $h$ in general...

Comment: What if $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}$ and $g(z) = \frac{1}{z}$?

Comment: $1/z^2$ is not a simple pole.

Comment: Actually, $1/z^2$ is not a simple pole so it doesn't fit as an example. I edited it out of my question as well.

Comment: Right. There is no such term as "a simple pole" in my language, so this assumption kind of slipped my mind. I should have checked what it meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edit later - if one has simple poles, the constant $a/b$ works for $h$ where $a$ is the residue of $f$ and $b$ is the residue of $g$ at $z_0$, so the proof is trivially one line)

The result is true if and only if the order of the pole of $g$ is equal or higher to the order of the pole of $f$ (the statement mentions simple poles, but your example has poles of order $1$ and $2$, so I am treating the general case). Let the order of the poles for $f$ and $g$ at $z_0$ be $m,n$ respectively

One way is obvious since for any finite function $h: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ (doesn't need to be analytic, continuous etc), if $k(z)=f(z)-h(z)g(z)$ is finite (no singularities), then $(z-z_0)^nk$ is finite and since $(z-z_0)^nh(z)g(z)$ is also finite, it follows that $(z-z_0)^nf(z)$ is finite, or $m \le n$

Conversely, assume $m \le n$, then we show we can find an entire function $h$ as required (a polynomial of degree at most $n$ will work as we will see from the proof), by considering $f_1(z), g_1(z)$ the principal parts of $f,g$ at $z_0$ (in other words $f-f_1, g-g_1$ are entire; we note that

$f_1(z)=\frac{Q(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}, g_1(z)=\frac{P(z)}{(z-z_0)^n}, \deg Q = m-1, \deg P=n-1, P(z_0) \ne 0, Q(z_0) \ne 0$ and we claim that we can find $h$ polynomial of degree at most $n$ s.t $(z-z_0)^{n-m}Q-h(z)P(z)$ has a zero of order $n$ at $z_0$, which obviously implies that $f-hg$ is entire.

We take $h(z)=(z-z_0)^{n-m}h_1(z)$ and then we need $h_1(z_0)P(z_0)=Q(z_0)$ which we get uniquely and non-zero since $P(z_0) \ne 0, Q(z_0) \ne 0$; so $Q-h_1P$ has a zero at $z_0$; differentiating we need $Q'-h_1'P-h_1P'$ to have a zero there, but since we know $Q',h_1,P,P'$ at $z_0$ and since $P(z_0) \ne 0$ we determine $h_1'(z_0)$ uniquely; now it is clear that we can continue differentiating since at each step forcing $Q-h_1P$ to have a higher order zero at $z_0$ by taking the next derivative, all the terms are determined except $h_1^{(k)}(z_0)P(z_0)$, where $k$ is the order we need now, and again $P(z_0)=0$ gives $h_1^{(k)}(z_0)$ uniquely. In particular we need to determine an entire function $h_1$ given $h_1(z_0) \ne 0, h_1'(z_0),...h_1^{(n-m)}(z_0)$ and it is obvious that a polynomial of degree at most $n-m$ works for $h_1$, hence a polynomial of degree at most $n$ works for $h=(z-z_0)^{n-m}h_1$ so we are done!

Comment: Thank you. Would this also work if $f$ and $g$ had two simple poles, $z_{0}$ and $z_{1}$, in common?

Comment: Need to find $h$ with  $h(z_0), h(z_1)$ given, so a degree at most $1$ polynomial will do- same for any number of simple poles by interpolating the residues; a bit more care allows to interpolate principal parts of higher order as long as the pole orders satisfy the required inequality at each pole